# Xampp cannot be installed on Ventura macOS

Tags: xampp, macos-ventura

I downloaded Xampp from the official website and it does not install or open, it does not even respond.

The official website link : [download Xampp for macOS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/)

MacOS : Ventura Version 13.0.1

---

I double-click, but nothing happens.

I tried right click then open, but nothing happens.
[image: Xampp installation box]

Comment: huh sourceforge? i thought xampp is now moved to github? and their official website is https://apachefriends.org, am i wrong? and someone had the [same issue](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=82195&p=277841) sometime in the past. it says the issue was due to "apple not whitelisting xampp" thing. don't know if its the actual cause though, i have never used apple product in my life so far.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I was double-clicking on the Xampp installer file to install.
The right way is to Right-click on the Xampp installer file and select open then it will ask password of your system to continue installation.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254713456

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings/ Confidentiality and Security /

Scroll down under "Security", you will find "Authorize application downloaded from"

And then directly below must be a message: installation of Xampp has been block, with the possibility to authorize it.